# Transfer from Terminal 3 to Terminal 5 at Heathrow Airport

Tags: international-travel

I (Pakistani) have a possible travel itinerary from USA to Saudi Arabia via UK Heathrow airport. From the airline website it says that I need to move from Terminal 3 (arrival from USA) to Terminal 5 of Heathrow airport.
Do I need to pass the border check/immigration?
If so then do I need to have UK transit visa or some sort?
I have residence permit visa (Iqama) for Saudi Arabia.

Comment: Would your two flights be on the same ticket? What are the arrival/departure times of the flights? Also, I suppose you have a valid visa or PR status for the USA?

Comment: Try https://www.heathrow.com/connecting-flights

Comment: @Traveller https://www.heathrow.com/at-the-airport/airport-maps/travel-between-terminals is actually more relevant as it explicitly mentions airside buses for people with connecting tickets - the page you linked is more applicable if the bookings are separate and you need to claim your baggage

Comment: @ChrisH-UK The connecting flights link says it for connecting flights that are arranged upon flight booking and have a link to other info for self-connected flights